# I get a nullPointerException calling a function from some methods and not from others

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, subclass, greenfoot

I'm using an environment called `Greenfoot`, a simple Java based 2d game engine, however I do not think the issue is related to `Greenfoot`, but java in general.

In Greenfoot, there is a `World` class, in which all of the `Actors` (just objects) interact with each other.

Whenever you create the `World` (it is constructed each time you start the game) you are actually creating a `MyWorld` object, which extends world and you can write your own code into.

My specific game is Chess, and my problem is related to the `enpassant` rule.

All of my chess pieces are children of one super class `Piece` which in turn is a child of the `Greenfoot` class `Actor`. For every piece except the `pawn`, they use the method in `Piece` `makeMove(x, y)`, shown here.

```
protected void makeMove(int x, int y)
{
    MyWorld w = (MyWorld)getWorld();
    if(canMove(x, y))
    {
        w.mainBoard.movePiece(getX(), getY(), x, y);
        w.makeMove();
        w.displayBoard();
        w.setEnPassant(-1);
    }
}
```

The first line gets the world the object is in, using the `getWorld()` method. Since `getWorld()` returns an object of type `World`, but my actors are in the object of type `MyWorld`, I just use casting.

There is no scenario in which `getWorld()` will be called and a `MyWorld` will not be returned. Nothing else here is super important, it just checks if it is possible to make the move fed to it, and if so, all of the code inside just moves the piece and updates the board, all of this works.

Also, `setEnPassant` sets a variable stored in the `MyWorld` object to `-1`, I use this variable to tell if `enPassant` is a possible move or not, and I reset the value in `makeMove` since `makeMove` will be called every turn.

The problem comes from the `Pawn` class, which extends `Piece`. To make `enPassant` work, I have to override the `makeMove` method inside of `Pawn`, see here:

```
protected void makeMove(int x, int y)
{
    int y1 = getY();
    super.makeMove(x, y);
    
    if(Math.abs(y1 - y) == 2)
    {
        MyWorld w = (MyWorld)getWorld();
        w.setEnPassant(getX());
    }
}
```

First, I store the current `y` value (the up and down coordinate). Then, I call `super.makeMove(x, y)`, which moves the piece to its new spot.

Next, I have an `if-statement` which checks whether or not the pawn moved 2 squares. The only time this can happen is at the very beginning, and if the pawn does move two squares it attempts to set the `enPassant` value to whichever column it is in. This is essentially broadcasting "I am available to be en passanted," and if there is a pawn on the other side who is in the proper spot, it will see that there is an en passant it can make.

The problem I am having is only on the very last line. Defining `MyWorld w` works, but calling `setEnPassant()` throws a `NullPointerException`. In fact, any method I call here throws a `NullPointerException`. No matter what I do with the object `w`, a `NullPointerException` is thrown.

I've done a few things which patch the issue, like for some reason moving `super.makeMove(x, y)` to the end of the method causes no problems. However, I need it to be at the beginning so that it does not immediately reset the `EnPassant` value to -1.

Another very strange solution I found was by changing the return type of `makeMove` in both `Piece` and `Pawn` to `MyWorld`. In Piece, I return the world `w`, and in `Pawn`, I use that same world `w` to set the en passant value. So instead of saying

```
MyWorld w = (MyWorld)getWorld();
```

I write

```
MyWorld w = super.makeMove(x, y);
```

There may be some more elegant ways of handling en passant but I don't really want to hear about any of those. Really I would just like to know why there's an error here and not in other places, and why the strange fixes I found made it not throw the `NullPointerException`.

Comment: I appreciate the amount of effort you put into this question - however most devs can understand code *much faster* than reading about something which tries to help them understand the code. Try editing your question to include a [reprex] and just describe your issue.

Comment: You might also adding some print statements where you try to use an object.   E.g. `w.makemove()`.  print `w`

Comment: Can you add code for getWorld() also?

Comment: The reason a NullPointerException is thrown is probably that w is null, because getWorld() is returning null.  In Greenfoot, getWorld() returns null if the object has been removed from the world.  So my guess is that one of these methods in the parent's makeMove is removing the pawn from the world.